How to add lib folder in pom.xml with many jar files
I have the lib folder under root of my maven project which contains many jar files.
How we can add this one folder all alone under pom.xml
As a temporary solution i have added each jars as dependency but my pom.xml is huge now.
How can it be done so that just one folder {lib} is considered for dependencies

Why do you have a lib folder to start with. That beats the purpose of using maven in the first place.

The so called temporary solution is the correct solution... exept that there are usually a number of transitive dependencies which you only need to define a few and the other dependencies are picked up by them indirectly... but I can't say what exactly because I don't know the jar files (deps) in detail... may be you can give some examples here...

(1) There is no better solution, (2) But you can consider adding another Maven Module: my-temp-lib, (<packaging>pom</packaging>) move these external jars here, and move the dependent settings to my-temp-lib's pom.xml, (3) Then set your original app to depend on my-temp-lib,(<type>pom</type><scope>import</scope>) so that your app's pom.xml will become simple.

@M.Deinum My project is of ant build and migrating it to maven.

THen stop using the lib folder, instead figure out which libraries that are and just add them as managed dependencies (sa you should). Adding them from the lib folder as system dependencies will only introduce other issues and complexities.
